# error when trying to make my mysql ndb cluster disk based

Tags: mysql

In trying to make my cluster disk-based, I issue the following command:

```
CREATE LOGFILE GROUP LG1 ADD UNDOFILE 'undo1.log' 
INITIAL_SIZE = 150M UNDO_BUFFER_SIZE = 164M ENGINE NDBCLUSTER;
```

and get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '150M UNDO_BUFFER_SIZE = 164M 
ENGINE NDBCLUSTER' at line 1
```

This is copied exactly from the docs manual so what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

(The cluster works in memory but I need the disk space).

Using `mysql-5.5.29 ndb-7.2.10`

EDIT: [link to doc manual](https://blogs.oracle.com/LinuxJedi/entry/mysql_cluster_disk_data_tables)

Comment: Maybe link to the exact docs URL that you have this from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this command doesn't translate the M or G after a value so instead of 2M, you have to put 2097152 (1024 * 1024 * 2).

So the command should be

```
CREATE LOGFILE GROUP LG1 ADD UNDOFILE 'undo1.log' 
INITIAL_SIZE = 157286400 UNDO_BUFFER_SIZE = 171966464 ENGINE NDBCLUSTER;
```